# Adding Tile Overlays to bing map in wpf is flickering?

Tags: c#, wpf, bing

I am trying to add weather overlays onto a bing map in WPF using weather central. I have already accomplished this in a web application and I tried to employ similar logic and it sort of worked but it seems that I have a bug. I basically call for new overlays every time there is a view change and clear off the old ones, using the {quadkey} system that bing has and weather central works with. This worked in the web application and is sort of working but the tiles keep flickering. It seems that the tiles are for different zoom levels and it can't decide which to choose? I am not really sure. Thanks for your help.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.MapTileLayer tileLayer;

    private double tileOpacity = .7;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MapTileOverlay.ViewChangeEnd += new EventHandler<Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.MapEventArgs>(MapTileOverlay_ViewChangeEnd);
    }

    void MapTileOverlay_ViewChangeEnd(object sender, Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.MapEventArgs e)
    {
        MapTileLayer.Children.Clear();

        tileLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.MapTileLayer();

        Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.TileSource tileSource = new Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.TileSource("http://datacloud.wxc.com/?type=tile&bing={quadkey}&datatype=forecast&var=Clouds&time=now&vs=0.9&passkey=our_key");

        tileLayer.TileSource = tileSource;
        tileLayer.Opacity = tileOpacity;
        MapTileOverlay.Children.Add(tileLayer);
    }
```

}